# Permuting movable construction

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

So I have an aggregate class `Foo` which takes moveable and (indirectly) copyable arguments (A class called `Image_t`, and a `std::unique_ptr<Map>`, and Map can clone itself).

I want to give the end user flexibility in how they create the class. So I have a "copy-like" constructor and a "move-like" constructor:

```
  typdef std::unique_ptr<Map> MapPtr;

  ///
  ///@brief Copy build constructor
  ///
  Foo(const Image_t& image, const MapPtr& map_ptr) :
  image_(image),
  geo_locatormap_(map_ptr->clone())
  {

  }

  ///
  ///@brief Move build constructor
  ///
  Foo(Image_t&& image, MapPtr&& map_ptr) :
  image_(std::move(image))
  geo_locatormap_(std::move(map_ptr))
  {

  }
```

Now ideally, I'd like to have `Foo(const Image_t& image, MapPtr&& map_ptr)` and `Foo(Image_t&& image, const MapPtr& map_ptr)` as well, but I'm feeling like this is duplicating  effort. Is there a quick way to do this? Or is this type of constructor frowned upon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use type deduction, perfect forwarding and a little helper:

```
static MapPtr&& map_forward( MapPtr&& m ) { return std::move( m ); }
static MapPtr map_forward( const MapPtr& m ) { return m->clone(); }

template<typename I, typename M>
Foo(I&& i, M&& m) :
image_{std::forward<I>(i)},
geo_locatormap_{map_forward(std::forward<M>(m))}
{

}
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I didn't think to use an external helper function in my example below. Yours is a lot cleaner.

Comment: @bstamour Thanks. I often use little helpers as they also scale better, think what happens if you have three or four of those parameters.

Comment: Very true. I'm going to add that idea to my toolbox ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just when I think I get RHR, this throws me for a loop...So I'm guessing the template parameter is to pick up const-ness, but I am a little confused at how, if I have `const Image_t a; Foo foo(a,std::move(some_ptr));`, how do the template parameters resolve? Do you got a link that explains this?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams This is called [**perfect forwarding**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001), the link explains it in depth. It's a bit complicated but there is just no simple way to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, since you can't just perfectly forward the `map_ptr` through (unless you use a helper function like in Daniel Frey's answer), you will need to handle that case separately. One method I can think of to cut your constructor count down to two is something like this:

```
// Clone the map.
template <typename Image>
Foo(Image&& img, MapPtr const& map_ptr)
    : image_{ std::forward<Image>(img) },
      geo_locatormap_{ map_ptr->clone() }
{ }

// move the map.
template <typename Image>
Foo(Image&& img, MapPtr&& map_ptr)
    : image_{ std::forward<Image>(img) },
      geo_locatormap_{ std::move(map_ptr) }
{ }
```

The Image&& syntax will bind to any lvalue/rvalue reference, and with `std::forward` you'll get the best operation for the type.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to define only one version:
`Foo(Image_t&& image, MapPtr&& map_ptr)`

Take a look for example at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293668.aspx) for more details.